# iphone device black colour screen blinkng in my jquery mobile phonegap app navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, css, cordova

When the navigating the page it is getting black screen blinking .

i am displaying the listview each list will go (onclick) separate page (details).

In this list top 5 (onclick) its not blinking screen it is moving smoothly.

After that (>5)list (onclick) it is blinking navigating to the next page .

please any idea help me .

thanks ,

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-page {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```